# System.setProperty in JUnit testing

Tags: java, file, testing, junit, system

I am trying to invoke a IO Exception for the `createTempFile` method of the `java.io.File` class for one of my test cases.

I have figured that one way to do so is to set the Property value for a single test case as follows:

```
class TestClass {
    @Test
    testCase1() {
         // do something
    }

    @Test
    testCase2() {
        String oldValue = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/no/such/dir");
        // invoke test case
        System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", oldValue);
    }
```

However, the issue I encounter is that although I am setting the system property in a single test case (`testCase2`) only, it affects ALL OTHER test cases in the entire class such as `testCase` (and test folder).

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I tried to print the value of `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", oldValue)` for test cases where I did not change the property and it appears to be correct.

Comment: Why don't you use try clause for your test case and put setproperty (old value) in a finally clause? It will definitively corect your path if you get an error during your tests.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies not in the setting of the property, but in the fact that the JDK initializes the directory used for `File.createTempFile` only once, and uses that single initialized directory. The same goes when using the methods from `Files` to create temporary files or directories.

If you can change the original code, use the overloaded variants that allow you to set the directory yourself. For instance:

```
// File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix");
File tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix", new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
```

---

There's also an issue with how you set and, more importantly, reset the system property. If the test fails the reset will not occur. You can use a try-finally block, or even simpler, use [JUnit Pioneer](https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/system-properties/):

```
class TestClass {
    @Test
    testCase1() {
         // do something
    }

    @Test
    @SetSystemProperty(key = "java.io.tmpdir", value = "/no/such/dir")
    testCase2() {
        // invoke test case
    }
```